# Array returning an empty array outside of PFQuery with Parse

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, tableview, pfquery

I'm trying to populate the array postCaptions.
I need to return this array to numberOfRowsInSection for my table view, but it returns an empty array every time.

```
  var postCaptions = [String]()

  query2.whereKey("userid", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId!)                        
  query2.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in   
        if let userPosted = objects {       
           for object in userPosted {         
               if let userPost = object as? PFObject {        
                  self.postImageFiles.append(userPost["userPostImage"] as! PFFile)                                      
                  self.postLocation.append(userPost["userPostLocation"] as! String)
                  self.postCaptions.append(userPost["postCaption"] as! String)
                  print(self.postCaptions.count) //returns value of 2 for the two posts that I've made                
                  self.tableView.reloadData()            
                  self.refresher.endRefreshing()
               }
            }
         }

   })          
   print(self.postCaptions.count) //Returns empty array
```

I know that the issue is with the order of the threading and I understand that, but I'm not sure exactly what I can do to make the array remain populated outside of the query. I've seen this as a method for solving this problem, but I really haven't found a straightforward answer for how I can fix this problem in my code. If someone could provide an answer that works with my code that would be amazing!:) I've been stuck with this problem for more than a week now

```
 var postCaptions = [String]() {
didSet {
    // Do any execution that needs to wait for postCaptions here.
}
 }
```

**cellForRowAt

```
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userPhotoFeedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

    if PFUser.current()?.objectId != nil {

        cell.userUsername.text = PFUser.current()?.username

    }


    //downloads images for user profile pic
    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

        if let imageData = data {

            let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

            cell.userProfilePic.image = downloadedImage

        }


    }

    //downloades images and items to populate user post
    postImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

        if let userPostImageData = data {

            let downloadedUserPostImage = UIImage(data: userPostImageData)

            cell.userFeedPhoto.image = downloadedUserPostImage

        }


    }

    cell.postLocation.text = postLocation[indexPath.row]

    cell.postCaption.text = postCaptions[indexPath.row]

    cell.userFeedPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "OrangeFuego")

    cell.userProfilePic.image = UIImage(named: "usericon.png")

    return cell

}
```

Comment: `findObjectsInBackground` works asynchronously. The print line is executed before the data are returned. Put the print line into the completion block.

Comment: Yes but I need to delay the calling of numberOfRowsInSection until the completion block is done loading, and thus has given postCaptions a value

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` is called from the framework. Populate your data source array and call `reloadData()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your issue it's rather simple. Set `var postCaptions = [String]()` as a global variable within the desired class. Then append your values from iterations to it the way you've done. Then the postCaptions values can be accessed in other parts of your code and you can use the count property.

Comment: The variable isn't the problem, the problem lies in the fact that findObjectsInBackground never finishes before numberOfRowsInSection is called, so the array is always 0

Answer (score 0):

Since the method `findObjectsInBackground` suggests that it is executed in the background, that means it has nothing to do with your UI, therefore your array will remain empty until this function is completed. At the moment you print that array, this function has not yet completed, so `postCaptions` will be empty for now.

And also that's why the numberOfRows will be zero.

I think what you need to do is to put this query into `viewDidLoad` or your designated initialiser, and call `tableView.reloadData()` as you did inside the completion block. Also, you might want to declare a Bool, to determine whether the table is loading or not, and in your completion block, set the isLoading to false after successfully executing the query.

```
query2.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

    if let userPosted = objects {
        self.isLoading = false

        for object in userPosted {

            if let userPost = object as? PFObject {

                self.postImageFiles.append(userPost["userPostImage"] as! PFFile)

                self.postLocation.append(userPost["userPostLocation"] as! String)

                self.postCaptions.append(userPost["postCaption"] as! String)

                print(self.postCaptions.count) //returns value of 2 for the two posts that I've made

             }

         }

         self.tableView.reloadData()

         self.refresher.endRefreshing()

     }

 })
```

and inside your `numberOfRowsInSection` :

```
if isLoading { //you need to declare isLoading 
    return 1 //maybe a dummy cell to tell user the table is loading
} else {
    return postCaptions.count
}
```

Comment: I like where this is going, however I tried it and isLoading will never equal false, because findObjectsInBackground is always going to be still loading by the time NumberOfRowsInSection is called. I need some way of waiting until findObjectsInBackground is finished before calling the rest.

Comment: @FinnWolff Perhaps you should put `reloadData()` and `self.isLoading = false` outside your `for-in` loop. See my edited answer above. Since you've called `reloadData()` after the query(background thread) has completed execution, so in theory, `isLoading` should be false after you set it. Because every time when `reloadData()` is called, `numberOfRows` method will be called.

Comment: So I added print("IT WORKED") to the if isLoading = false return postCaptions.count part of numberOfRowsInSection. It did work!!! The array is populated and everything, however when I scroll through the feed in the app it crashes, saying: Index out of Range

Comment: I thought that populating the array and having it returned for numberOfRowsInSection wouldn't cause an index out of range error. Do you know why this might be happening? : /

Comment: @FinnWolff Can you show me the code inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? I think that's the reason.

Comment: Yup check out ***cellForRowAt that I added to my original post up top

Comment: @FinnWolff Could you do some 'print' to see exactly which line is causing the crash? Because you have a lot of array, it might be due to one of them is empty or something.

Comment: Yeah I'll try doing some prints. It's weird because it shows my first post and all the details downloaded from Parse, but when I try to scroll to show the next one in crashes. Where would you recommend running prints to check for errors?

Comment: I removed ImageFiles getDataInBackground from cellForRowAtIndex and it works now!!! However, I still need a way to get the data for ImageFiles... Any suggestions?